# "currently running survey" or "currently-running survey"?

Tags: adverbs, hyphenation

I still struggle to understand exactly when to use hyphens when adverbs are involved.  Which of the following is correct? ABC is an acronym representing the actual name of the survey.

"I use results from the currently running ABC survey."

"I use results from the currently-running ABC survey."

Comment: I would say, "*I use results from the current ABC survey*".  The operative word is 'current', 'running' is redundant (a survey *runs* by definition).

Comment: That doesn't sound quite right to me.

Comment: The results from last year's ABC survey suggested that ... .  Results from the current ABC survey suggest that ...

Comment: @Dan, but the survey isn't complete yet.  It is running right now.  It is a galaxy survey using 300 nights on a telescope, and we're in the middle of that.

Comment: I would understand that "*...the current study*" is not yet over.  If I wanted to emphasise this fact I would say "*...the current, ongoing/continuing survey*", although I don't think this emphasis is needed.

Answer (score 2):

The rule is that the adverb *very* and adverbs ending in *-ly* are never hyphenated, so "I use results from the currently running ABC survey" is correct.

Comment: Follow-up question, what about "more"? As in, "more realistic system"?